# redirect url with dots aspnet webforms

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webforms

The site is a ASP.NET webforms site using the .NET4 framework.

I've been asked to add a 301 for a URL like: `/.../all-offers.aspx`

With a 301 added (in web.config with the rest) if I request that path with the site running on Cassini I get a 400, Bad Request. On our dev server its a 404, Not Found.

I assumed it was malformed and wouldn't work but I'm thinking if it's returning a 404 it can be intercepted and redirected.

So, is this a legit URL? If so, am I missing a trick to get it to redirect?

Cheers

Comment: Were you asked to do this by a developer or an SEO? This smells slightly of an SEO having misread an unsubstantiated blog post by a "google insider".

Comment: I'm the developer and the client pays cold, hard cash to SEO "experts" so they must be right :) I think most SEOs make a living from unsubstantiation.

Comment: It obviously depends upon your relationship with your client, but personally I'd be inclined to let the SEO know (via your client, so they see that you're trying to be cooperative) that the URL isn't working as expected, then ask for the source so you can check it to ensure that there aren't any nuances to their solution that you're missing.

Comment: Feel free to post any response as part of an answer, by the way. If necessary, include the source that the SEO has used. That way, if anyone else comes across the same issue they'll have this question to refer to.

Comment: IIRC, their checking google webmaster tools (is this the source you mean?) for high value incoming URLs not returning a 200. I simply get a spreadsheet with 2 columns: old url and new url.

Comment: Ah, so someone is visiting that path on their site? It's not a legitimate URL, but you should be able to use an HTTP redirect rule to catch it within IIS itself, and issue the redirection to the "proper" page outside of .net itself.

Comment: The site was redone years ago and apparently that URL is still used so I am to redirect it to the current, live offers page (which is a .net page). Yeah, I figured I should be able to capture it as under IIS it throws a 404 - but I've added it to the list of a hundred or so existing redirects and only this one doesn't work...